# Which one is a better way to copy an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, copy

currently I am using two ways to copy an object:
the first one is

```
let obj2 = {...obj}
```

the second one is

```
let obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj)
```

which one should be the recommended one? thanks

Comment: How do you spread an object? I'd say the second one ?

Comment: Perhaps this is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: ES2015 suggests the Object.assign() in order to execute such operation. Learn more https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @adeneo, this is my .babellrc 
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're compiling with Babel, they are basically the same:

```
var a = {...b};
```

Compiles into:

```
var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };

var a = _extends({}, b);
```

I suppose the object spread syntax is slightly better since it will still work if your environment doesn't support `Object.assign`.

Comment: Babel's "try it out" page: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20a%20%3D%20%7B...b%7D%3B